# Ignore certain changes in git diff

Tags: command-line, bash, git, diff

Is it possible to get a report from git diff or related commands that excludes a certain category of change?

I've been asked to review a change where a huge number of files have undergone the equivalent of s/2016/2017/g. (We upgraded a third-party jar and as a result many of our imports now reference a different package.)

Are there options for viewing this diff from the command line but suppressing all changes that just consist of something like the following, so that I can focus on any logic changes?

Ignore:

```
-import com.example.2016_2.util.Utility
+import com.example.2017_2.util.Utility
```

Keep:

```
-Utility util = new Utility();
+Utility util = Utility.create();
```

If the answer is to write my own script and integrate via `git diff --porcelain` or by setting `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`, I am certainly game; just wondering if

1. this is supported out of the box and somehow I missed it in the man page;
2. there are other git diff* commands I can use for this;
3. if an appropriate diff executable already exists that I can provide via `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`

Comment: `--word-diff` and `--word-diff-regex` may help by just highlighting changes on 2016/2017 without showing the full line as changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of way to diff files, `git diff` is fine but there are others. Faced with the same task, I would:

- check out the code with the later changes
- copy the whole code tree in another directory
- revert the 2016/2017 change in that copy
- in the git tree, check out the historic commit
- do a recursive comparison  between the two trees (BeyondCompare on Windows, `kdiff3` on Linux)

Comment: I would do the same but just *using* git: create a new, temporary branch based on `new`, revert the substitution commit and compare to `old`. That way git can help by detecting moves/renames AND you can use your IDE.

Comment: "copy the whole code tree in another directory" you can use `git worktree` feature for that